# mport OVF from vSphere ESXi to VMware Workstation 7 Problem 

Tags: vmware-esxi

I exported a Win2K3 OVF format from vSphere ESXi 4.0 (pre update 1). I tried to import it into VMware workstation 7 build (203739 ). But, I got the error "The OVF descriptor file could not be parsed". I have tried this on two different workstation running VMware Workstation 7 and export two different OVF file and they got the same error message. Is vSphere ESXi 4.0 compatible with VMware Workstation 7?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

There are two versions of OVF; 1.0 and 0.9.  Try VMware's [OVFtool](http://www.vmware.com/downloads/download.do?downloadGroup=OVF-TOOL-1-0) to convert the OVF.